# Is an overlay network still necessary?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

When using Istio with Kubernetes, is an overlay network still required for each node?

I have read the FAQ's and the documentation, but cannot see anything that directly references this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Istio is built upon the Kubernetes. It creates sidecar containers in the Kubernetes Pods for routing requests, gathering metrics and so on. But still, it requires a way for Pods to communicate with each other. Therefore, Kubernetes network overlay is required.

For additional information, you can start from the following [link](https://medium.com/google-cloud/simplifying-microservices-with-istio-in-google-kubernetes-engine-part-i-849555f922b8).

Comment: Thanks although the doco keeps mentioning "Service-Service communication" as well as the link you pointed me at so it was not clear that the overlay network was still a requirement.